# How to combine the values of different cells into strings of our own format and store it in the third cell?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table that has two columns namely Description and Amount. I want to write those details in a third cell in the form of Description1-Amount1, Description2-Amount2, and so on till there is an empty row. Please look at the image for better understanding.
[image: The tabular column]

So, now in the Sheet 2 in cell A1, I want the content as Dad-500, Chegg-123. Suppose if there are more items, I want them to be subsequently added.
I have designed a macro such that on click, whatever Values are present in the table at that point of time should be saved in Cell A1 of Sheet2.

My code is:

```
Sub database
Dim emptyRow As Long

Dim mix1 As String

mix1 = "=CONCATENATE(Sheet1!C5,""-"",Sheet1!D5)"

Sheet2.Activate

  'Determine emptyRow
  emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = mix1

End Sub
```

In the above code, `Sheet1!C5,""-"",Sheet1!D5` represents Description (C column) and Amount (D column) respectively.

This code copies the formula into the second sheet. But I want those details to be converted as a string and then store in the empty cell (A1), such that next time if I run the macro with the different set of values in the table, those details should be copied in Cell A2 (since that is the next empty cell) and the values in cell A1 should not be changed since it is converted to string.

Now the problem I am facing is if I run the macro for the second time, both the values in cell A1 and A2 are changing since both these cells contains formulas and not strings.

Please help me as to how to combine the values of different cells into strings of our own format and store it in the third string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transfer the values without creating a formula.

```
sub database
    with sheet2
        .cells(.rows.count, "A").end(xlup).offset(1, 0) = _
          sheet1.cells(5, "C").value2 & chr(45) & sheet1.cells(5, "D").value2
    end with
end sub
```

Comment: Your code is giving the value of only the first row. It is returning the Value as "Dad-500".  But I want the code to read all the rows in the table and combine everything. Basically I want answer like "Dad-500, Chegg-123". Please see the image I have posted along with the question. The code should display all the values till there is an empty row. Right now there are only two rows namely Dad and Chegg. But if there are three values like Dad, Chegg and Bro, then it should display it as "Dad-500, Chegg-123, Bro-350." Please reform your code little bit. I think we need to use for loop.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Please help little more. Please see my first comment.

Comment: Yes, I read that part of your narrative. However, that (e.g. '*how do I create a loop?*') is a different question from what you asked which was '*how do I concatenate two strings without a formula?*'. If you need a loop, then write a loop. If you run into trouble, post back with a new question.